# sed replace single/double quoted text?

Tags: text, replace, sed

Having some difficulty in replacing some single/double quoted text with **sed** and was wondering what's the correct method for these 2 examples

to change Memached.ini file contents from

```
[server]
server[] = "localhost:11211"
```

to

```
[server]
server[] = "localhost:11211"
server[] = "localhost:11212"
```

and to change memcache.php file contents for these lines from

```
define('ADMIN_USERNAME','username');    // Admin Username
define('ADMIN_PASSWORD','password');    // Admin Password

$MEMCACHE_SERVERS[] = 'mymemcache-server1:11211'; // add more as an array
$MEMCACHE_SERVERS[] = 'mymemcache-server2:11211'; // add more as an array
```

to

```
define('ADMIN_USERNAME','myusername');  // Admin Username
define('ADMIN_PASSWORD','mypassword');      // Admin Password

$MEMCACHE_SERVERS[] = 'localhost:11211'; // add more as an array
$MEMCACHE_SERVERS[] = 'localhost:11212'; // add more as an array
```

I tried for example

```
sed -i 's/'ADMIN_USERNAME','memcache'/'ADMIN_USERNAME','u'/g' /var/www/html/memcache.php
```

while command runs, memcache.php file isn't changed at all ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can replace the single quotes in the sed command with double-quoted single quotes.  The shell sees a single quote as ending a string.  So, let it.  You had

```
sed -i 's/'ADMIN_USERNAME','memcache'/'ADMIN_USERNAME','u'/g' /var/www/html/memcache.php
```

But, if you replace the ' in the sed command with '"'"', then shell will see the first ' as ending the first single-quoted string, then "'" as a double-quoted single quote, and then the last ' as a beginning of a new single-quoted string.  That'd be

```
sed -i 's/'"'"'ADMIN_USERNAME'"'"','"'"'memcache'"'"'/'"'"'ADMIN_USERNAME'"'"','"'"'u'"'"'/g' /var/www/html/memcache.php
```

You should also be able to do '\'' in place of the ' within the command, for the same reason.

```
sed -i 's/'\''ADMIN_USERNAME\'',\''memcache\''/\''ADMIN_USERNAME\'',\''u\''/g' /var/www/html/memcache.php
```

But really, it'd be better to use an alternative mechanism.  I'd suggest defining the source and target strings as variables, and then put those in the sed string.

```
SRC="'ADMIN_USERNAME','memcache'"
DST="'ADMIN_USERNAME','u'"
sed -i "s/$SRC/$DST/g" /var/www/html/memcache.php
```

That's way more readable, and it makes it easier for you to handle the quoting mess in a sane way with bite-sized chunks.  Yay "shell variable contents aren't subject to word expansion unless you force it" knowledge. :)

Make sure you don't put a / in the $SRC or $DST variables, though. ;)

Answer (score 18):

You'll have to use hex escapes, for example, to do those replacements.

```
$ echo "'foo'" | sed 's/\x27foo\x27/\x27bar\x27/'
'bar'
```

You could also use octal escapes: `\o047` (that's a lower-case "Oh") or decimal escapes: `\d39`.

Comment: The best answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

To understand how to do this, you need to understand how the shell is messing with your quotes and backslashes as well as whether `sed` is messing with them.

Generally, it is easiest in the shell to use single quotes - except when the regex must match single quotes.  There are no special characters inside single quotes; the next single quote ends it.  Double quotes are much harder; backslashes and dollars and back-quotes are all special.

The first requirement is best handled by a single quoted `sed` expression:

> Change:
>
> ```
> [server]
> server[] = "localhost:11211"
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> [server]
> server[] = "localhost:11211"
> server[] = "localhost:11212"
> ```

For this, we could use:

```
-e '/^server\[] = "localhost:11211"/{p;s/11211/11212/}'
```

The shell simply sends everything inside the single quotes to `sed`, untouched.  The only special character to `sed` is the open square bracket.  That would start a character class except for the backslash before it.  The close square bracket is only special when you are in a character class, so it does not need escaping.  The actions on recognizing that line are to print the original, then do the 11212 for 11211 substitution; the default print will print the modified line.

The other part is a bit trickier.  Because the patterns contain single quotes, we're going to be best off using double quotes around the regex.

> Change:
>
> ```
> define('ADMIN_USERNAME','username');    // Admin Username
> define('ADMIN_PASSWORD','password');    // Admin Password
>
> $MEMCACHE_SERVERS[] = 'mymemcache-server1:11211'; // add more as an array
> $MEMCACHE_SERVERS[] = 'mymemcache-server2:11211'; // add more as an array
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> define('ADMIN_USERNAME','myusername');  // Admin Username
> define('ADMIN_PASSWORD','mypassword');      // Admin Password
>
> $MEMCACHE_SERVERS[] = 'localhost:11211'; // add more as an array
> $MEMCACHE_SERVERS[] = 'localhost:11212'; // add more as an array
> ```

The first two lines might be mappable using a single regex:

```
-e "s/^\(define('ADMIN_[A-Z]\{0,8\}','\)\([^']*'\)/\1my\2/"
```

This captures two parts - the `define('ADMIN_USERNAME','` as `\1` and the `username'` as `\2`, and the substitution places `my` between the two parts.  This was not too bad; the shell doesn't do anything special with any of the characters, so you just type what you want `sed` to see inside the double quotes.

The last two lines are trickier:

```
-e "s/^\(\$MEMCACHE_SERVERS\[] = '\)[^:]*\(:[0-9]*'\)/\1localhost\2/"
```

However, not much trickier; you just need to stop the shell from expanding the `$MEMCACHE_SERVERS` as a shell variable, which is why there's a backslash in front of the `$`.  The square bracket needs protection from `sed` as before.  The regex matches everything that isn't a colon and replaces it with `localhost`.

So, this script should work:

```
sed -e '/^server\[] = "localhost:11211"/{p;s/11211/11212/}' \
    -e "s/^\(define('ADMIN_[A-Z]\{0,8\}','\)\([^']*'\)/\1my\2/" \
    -e "s/^\(\$MEMCACHE_SERVERS\[] = '\)[^:]*\(:[0-9]*'\)/\1localhost\2/" \
    "$@"
```

However, I've only explained why it should work; I've not demonstrated that it does work!

Answer (score 1):

You either need to quote the quotes or escape the quotes.  Did you try checking what sed sees when you give it that last command?

> sed -i 's/'ADMIN_USERNAME','memcache'/'ADMIN_USERNAME','u'/g' /var/www/html/memcache.php

Try this:

> echo sed -i 's/'ADMIN_USERNAME','memcache'/'ADMIN_USERNAME','u'/g' /var/www/html/memcache.php

It gives this:

> sed -i s/ADMIN_USERNAME,memcache/ADMIN_USERNAME,u/g /var/www/html/memcache.php

Oops!  Your single quotes were not interpreted how you thought.  An easy workaround for this case is to quote protect your sed command from the shell with double quotes instead.

> sed -i "s/'ADMIN_USERNAME','memcache'/'ADMIN_USERNAME','u'/g" /var/www/html/memcache.php

Comment: Thanks quoting entire sed command worked for first part but 2nd part hitting error

[* sed -i "s/$MEMCACHE_SERVERS[] = 'mymemcache-server1:11211';/$MEMCACHE_SERVERS[] = 'localhost:11211';/g" /var/www/html/memcache.php *]

Comment: @p4guru, in this case it's because of the dollar sign, which tells the shell to dereference a variable (in this case called MEMCACHE_SERVERS). You could escape the dollar sign with a backslash: `"s/\$MEMCACHE_SERVERS..."`. Other solutions would be to change the double quotes back to single quotes, and then escape your sed command's single quotes with a backslash. Finally, for an amusing dirty hack, you could make MEMCACHE_SERVERS an actual variable, and give it the value MEMCACHE_SERVERS: `MEMCACHE_SERVERS=MEMCACHE_SERVERS sed -i ...`.