# SHELL - SED replacing text between " "

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I'm new at shell and SED in general. I am trying to replace a text in a file. This text is between " " and i am struggling to create the command...

The file has something like:
download_amule_tcp_port="42450"

My code:

```
TCPPort=44444

sed -i 's/^download_amule_tcp_port=\".*/download_amule_tcp_port=\"$TCPPort\"/' settings.conf
```

It is not working...

```
download_amule_tcp_port=$TCPPort"
```

Thanks for any help!

M

Comment: Variable does not expand between single quote, try use double quote. Test `echo "$TCPPort"` vs `echo '$TCPPort'`

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to proivde the correct syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed replace single/double quoted text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870253/sed-replace-single-double-quoted-text)

Comment: Can you have newlines within the quoted text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

==== EDIT ==== The correct syntax as in comments, should be:

```
TCPPort="44444"

sed -i "s/^download_amule_tcp_port=.*/download_amule_tcp_port=\"$TCPPo
rt\"/" settings.conf
```

This will work. thanks!

Comment: Seems good, you should mark your own answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 1):

the problem lies in the single quote, which prevents the variable,$TCPPort in this case, from being expanded to "44444".

the following code should work

```
TCPPort="44444"
sed -i 's/^download_amule_tcp_port=".*/download_amule_tcp_port="'"$TCPPort"'"/g' settings.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes and escape the inner double quotes:

```
sed -i "s/^download_amule_tcp_port=\".*/download_amule_tcp_port=\"$TCPPORT\"/" settings.conf
```

Btw, you set the variable `TCPPort` instead of `TCPPORT`.